# Build Android apk on Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, apk

I'm trying to build a android app on Unity3d and it never works (7 exeption). The errors are:

```
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

My Unity versión is 2019.3.7f1.

Answer (score 0):

Open the ‘mainTemplate.gradle’ file in a text editor and change build.gradle 3.4.0 version to 3.2.0.

‘mainTemplate.gradle’ Path is
“C:\Program Files\Unity2019.3.7f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\GradleTemplates\mainTemplate.gradle”

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'}
Change it like below

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'}

Comment: dependencies content is: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
**DEPS**} . Do I have to delete it?